# PHP variable needs to equal a value obtained from an sql query

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to use php to plot a graph. I want to plot the values returned from a count of results within a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tAnswer WHERE Answer1 = '1';
```

The query returns 3. I now want this 3 to become stored within a php variable.

How would I got about this?

Answer (score 1):

Alias COUNT(*) with a name like,

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM ...`

And then you can access it like you would any returned column, ie. `$row['C']`